# F# - Class member does not keep state

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I wrote a wrapper around List. I expect the internal list to keep state but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? The methods are definitely executed but the internal list is always empty.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open NUnit.Framework


type MyList() =
        member this.List = List<char>()
        member this.AddX =
            printfn "AddX called"
            this.List.Add('X')

        member this.CountX: int =
            printfn "CountX called"
            this.List.Count

[<Test>]
let TestX () =
    let mylist = MyList()
    mylist.AddX
    mylist.AddX
    Assert.AreEqual(2, mylist.CountX)
```

Tried putting a mutable keyword in different places (no success)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time you call the `List` member of `MyList`, it creates a new list, so the class isn't keeping internal state the way you want. (You can verify this by adding a `printfn` statement to the `List` method.)

To fix this problem, change the `List` member to be a [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties), which is initialized only once per class instance:

```ml
type MyList() =
        member val List = List<char>()
        ...
```

Alternatively, you can use a `let`-bound value instead:

```ml
type MyList() =
        let list = List<char>()
        member this.AddX = list.Add('X')
        member this.CountX = list.Count
```